# The welcome message I set does not work for me

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

the code keeps giving me this error and I'm using discord.js v14. I didn't find how to solve it

This is the base code I created:

```
   const { MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");
   const Welcome = require('../../settings/models/guild');

   module.exports = async (client, member) => {
    const { guild } = member

  
    Welcome.findOne({ guildID: member.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
      if (!data) {
        return;
      } else {
        const user = member.user;
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(data.welcomeChannel);

        var welcometxt = Welcome.findOne({ 
          guildID: member.guild.id,
        })
        welcometxt = welcometxt.replace('{member:mention}', `<@${member.user.id}>`);
        welcometxt = welcometxt.replace('{member:name}', `${member.user.username}`);
        welcometxt = welcometxt.replace('{member:id}', `${member.user.id}`);
        welcometxt = welcometxt.replace('{member:tag}', `${member.user.tag}`);
        welcometxt = welcometxt.replace('{member:createdAt}', `${member.user.createdAt}`);
        welcometxt = welcometxt.replace('{server:name}', `${member.guild.name}`);
        welcometxt = welcometxt.replace('{server:members}', `${member.guild.members.cache.size}`);

        channel.send(welcometxt)
      }
    });

  }
```

this is the error:

```
TypeError: welcometxt.replace is not a function
    at C:\Users\MihaiT\Desktop\Rovy\events\guild\guildMemberAdd.js:18:33
    at C:\Users\MihaiT\Desktop\Rovy\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5228:18
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

Comment: `replace()` is a string function, `welcometxt` is likely not a string. Log it and see what it's returning. I imagine it's an object

Comment: `Welcome.findOne` will return an object, the same as your first call to it. if its called `welcometxt` in the db, use the one from the previous call and it then be `data.welcometxt`